# How can I check read and write time to SD card on my rpi?

Tags: sd-card

I want to check the reading and writing time on my SD card on my RPI.

Comment: that's a linux question ... research how to time data transfer in linux

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a recent version of Raspberry Pi OS with Desktop. Run the Raspberry Pi Diagnostics from the menu.

It will perform sd card speed tests and produce a log.

https://www.raspberrypi.com/news/sd-card-speed-test/